# PHPMailer SMTP works on local server, but not on production server

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, google-apps, phpmailer

I have the following configuration for PHPMailer, which worked perfectly on my localhost machine, but doesn't send emails in production:

```
//Send a notification email
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = $username;
    $mail->Password = $password;
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['username'], $name);
    $mail->SetFrom("no-reply@a-domain-setup-in-google-apps.com", "No-Reply");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = $altBody;
    $mail->MsgHTML($bodyHTML);
    $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

When I set SMTP debug equal to `2`, here is what I get:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP bo7sm9593967igb.2 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [204.93.159.80] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 PIPELINING 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [204.93.159.80] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 PIPELINING 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 OK bo7sm9593967igb.2 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 OK bo7sm9593967igb.2 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Go ahead bo7sm9593967igb.2 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 OK 1341071123 bo7sm9593967igb.2
```

It all looks good, but I can't send emails any more.

I am positive my Google Apps account that this is sending emails from is configured properly (as it worked before), and my logon credentials are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the output it looks like it's working. Are you sure the email didn't go into spam or is somehow filtered by the recipients' address?

Comment: Why would it have been in production, but never in localhost testing?

Comment: Your production server could be on a graylist, or something. No clue. But the output clearly shows that your email was accepted.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can send emails from PHP, using PHPMailer?

Comment: Have you checked the "Sent mail" folder of the Google App email account?

Comment: @houbysoft The site is hosted on a `co.cc` domain. Could that possibly be where the issues are coming from?

Comment: @spryno724: [Google has banned all `.co.cc` domains](http://www.seroundtable.com/co-cc-google-removal-13644.html) from its index, I wouldn't be surprised if they had restrictions for email too. Consider getting a normal domain, `.co.cc` is associated with spam. I've never seen a legitimate site on `.co.cc` to be honest...

Comment: @houbysoft Gotcha ;) I've heard they deleted a TON of `co.cc` domains from their index, so emails not sending from there would also make sense. I have a legitimate `.com` domain and I can create a sub domain specifically for emailing. Thank you! If you want, type in your comment as an I answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your emails are most likely not delivering because `.co.cc` domains are associated with spam and generally non-legitimate sites; [Google has banned all `.co.cc` domains from its index](http://www.seroundtable.com/co-cc-google-removal-13644.html).

It would thus make sense that they are blocking or heavily filtering emails from these domains as well.

Consider using a normal domain, like one ending with `.com`.